# I need a way to keep adding custom objects to a file in a cycle

Tags: python, file

Essentially, I am trying to write some code that will keep adding my custom objects to a file in a cycle. Every iteration will save another object to that file, so that in the end the file will contain all of the objects, which I then want to add to a list. I don't want to completely re-write the file every time, just keep adding things to it.

Comment: Use append mode

Comment: @AleksanderK or create data object where you append you data and then save object to file

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for append mode: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

```
with open('some_file', 'a') as f:
    f.write('new line\n')
```